# Why is my simple for-each loop, on my collection of objects, not working (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a collection of objects, which is retrieved in JavaScript/JQuery through EL (at least that is what I think). I name the variable "countries". Upon calling alert(countries), my output is as expected. I have four elements, as it should be.

I thought it would be the easiest thing in the world, but for an unknown reason, it just doesn't work So... help?

```
var countries = "${requestScope.countries}";
```

alert(countries) gives the following output:

```
[beans.CountryBean@(id#), beans.CountryBean@(id#), 
beans.CountryBean@(id#), beans.CountryBean@(id#)]
```

@AaronDigulla suggested the following syntax:

```
$.each(countries, function(index, value) { ... });
```

But this, almost identical code, gives no output.

```
$.each(countries, function(index, value) { alert(index + "here");});
```

Am I just wrong in assuming it would produce 4 alerts?

Comment: What is this "EL" you speak of?

Comment: Question to the downvoters: Care to explain why you think this question is bad?

Comment: I can see that this is not a popular question. I want to make clear that I do have made an effort to figure this out, and the question should be clear enough. Feel free to downvote, but I would still appreciate pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.each(countries, function(index, value) { ... });`

[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) can iterate over all kinds of things (arrays, objects and JQuery selectors).

Next, you need to convert the beans to JavaScript. The browser can't understand `beans.CountryBean@(id#)`. Use a JSON framework like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to create a JSON string:

```
var countries = ${new Gson().toJson(requestScope.countries)};
```

note that you must not quote the string anymore; Gson will do this for you. But I fear this expression is out of the scope of what EL can do. In that case, you need to do the conversion elsewhere and put it into the EL context.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't seem to make it work. I have already searched through the page you have linked to, and I have tried most, if not all of the suggested syntaxes there. The following code gives me no output at all.

`$.each(countries, function(index, value) { alert(index + "here");});`

Comment: You should really use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` since it won't stop the script. use the developer tools of your browser to set a breakpoint in the code and then make sure that `countries` contains what you expect (and that you don't have any other errors).

Comment: thanks again. I do not have any experience with console.log(). I changed it, but on first attempt there was still no output. I expected it to appear in my eclipse-console, but I'll read some more to se if that was a valid assumption. 
Even though I haven't figured out my problem, and lost reputation points on this question, I have still learned two new things which I can use in the future, and that is what this site is all about for me. :)

Comment: `$.each(countries, function(index, value) { });` as it stands now, without anything inside the curly brackets, actually stops the execution, and breaks out of the function that contains the code. I am positively puzzled....

Comment: I found an error code in Chrome's inspector: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [beans.CountryBean@169fd6, beans.CountryBean@1579aa5, beans.CountryBean@69ee4e, beans.CountryBean@9c5cbd] `

Comment: It seems that the beans were not converted to JSON on the server before the data was sent to the client. See my edits.

Comment: I take it that they should. There is a lot of different languages/libraries one needs to master to make a web-app. I kinda hoped that JSTL, EL, JavaScript, SQL, JQuery, Java, XML, HTML and TLD would be enough... Oh well, thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I have found that my variable countries, is in fact just a string, containing the same as I would expect a collection.toString() to return. In other words, there are no "each" to iterate over. I found this thanks to your final answer, of interpretation, and JSON references. I hav enot had the time to solve the problem, but at least I understand it, and that is the hardest part right there. THANKS ALOT :)